# Replace icon with text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace an image icon with a text. Following is code:

```
if ($('td:contains("<i class="fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color"></i>")')) {
    var elem = $('td:contains("<div class='text-center'><i class="fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color"></i></div>")');
    elem.html($.trim(elem.html()).replace("<div class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color'></i></div>", "Facebook"));
}
```

It is not working. What is the issue?

Earlier I was using :

```
function changeToIcons() {
    if ($('td:contains("Facebook")')) {
        var elem = $('td:contains("Facebook")');
        elem.html($.trim(elem.html()).replace("Facebook", "<div class='text-center' value='Facebook'><i class='fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color'></i></div>"));
    }
}
```

This code is working fine. Now for my requirement I need to replace from icon to image.

Comment: @RishiPrakash well, I see syntax error in `var elem = ` line. What about you?

Comment: Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter suggests you don't even have valid JavaScript code :-? `$('td:contains("<div class='text....`

Comment: you seriously need to check your code... or change your IDE or something. It's hard to let that one go unnoticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using contains selector, you can simplify your code by using `find` and `replaceWith`.

Code:

```
var $myTd = $('td');

var $myDiv = $myTd.find('div.text-center');

if ($myDiv.find('i.fa.fa-facebook-official.cust-icon.fb-color').length > 0) $myDiv.replaceWith('Facebook');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0ck9nn85/

Comment: Yes, that's a  mistake.

Comment: @Regent that's a bug of StackOverflow, when I went to edit it. he has done right. he has replaced $myDiv content. But it is somehow showing $myTd here. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ($('td:contains("<i class="fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color"></i>")')) {
       /* var elem = $('td:contains("<div class="text-center"><i class=fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color"></i></div>")');
        elem.html($.trim(elem.html()).replace("<div class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color'></i></div>", "Facebook"));*/

if ($('td').find('div.text-center').find('i.fa.fa-facebook-official.cust-icon.fb-color').length > 0){
$('td .text-center').has('i.fa.fa-facebook-official.cust-icon.fb-color').replaceWith('‌​Facebook');
}
}
```

`var elem = $('td:contains("<div class='text-center'` <----single quotes are breaking the script.

ANOTHER MAJOR PROBLEM : You are not properly selecting DOM element.

//By the courtesy of Regent

working Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/0ck9nn85/1/

Comment: @Regent yes, workng on it

Comment: @Rishi what is the alternate for single quotes?

Comment: @jane I have corrected them. You can use the script in my answer. But yes as Regent pointed out, you are not selecting the Element properly. You need to make sure it reutrns a DOM element not a Boolean value/

Comment: @Rishi I'm not sure what it returns. Can you please explain how it will return DOM element

Comment: @jane yes,  have update the answer ,you must check it .

Comment: @Regent yes corrected that, more issues?

Comment: @RishiPrakash now you replace `div`s in **all** `td`s, not only in ones that have `i.fa.fa-facebook-official.cust-icon.fb-color` :)

Comment: @Regent May you please make necessary corrections? :)

Comment: @RishiPrakash here you go: `$('td .text-center').has('i.fa.fa-facebook-official.cust-icon.fb-color').replaceWith('Facebook');` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ck9nn85/1/).

Answer (score 0):

if you change

```
var elem = $('td:contains("<div class='text-center'><i class="fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color"></i></div>")');
```

to

```
 var elem = $('td:contains("<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official cust-icon fb-color"></i></div>")');
```

Quotation marks on text-center were wrong.

Comment: What about `contains("<div class="text-center">...`? It is not valid part of jQuery's selector.

Comment: @Regent there is another problem. That condition will always return true. Since it is a jquery object. Needs to check 'length' in that condition

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes, it looks like OP is not really familiar with jQuery. Let's just say that this long `contains` value looks very bad. I talk about checking for children existance using string with HTML...